# Copy single difference in kdiff3

Tags: kdiff3

Is it possible to copy only one change or many changes one by one in kdiff? There are such options in WinMerge which allow to copy chnge from one file to second file without merging.

I need to copy few changes from one file to another and want to do it manually.

Comment: If anyone is still interested I have simply switched to meld (meldmerge.org).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first of all, say we have a `left.txt` and a `right.txt`, you need to make sure that `right.txt` is placed on the right side of kdiff.

so it will be like this:

```
       left.txt       right.txt
1        a              b
2        b              b
3        c              b
```

say you only want the 3rd line in `left.txt` to be merged in `right.txt`

FIRST, align and split/join the diff to satisfy your needs.

You can find it in the help document, search:

*Manually Aligning Lines* and *Manually Joining and Splitting Diff Sections*

**Here comes the process**

1, click 'merge' on the toolbar

2, use `ctrl+shift+2` to apply all conflicts with right.txt(which is also B here)

the merge file will become:

```
1    b
2    b
3    b
```

3, select line 3, press `ctrl+1` that will select changes from `left.txt`. And the output file wlll be:

```
1    b
2    b
3    c
```

And I think that is what you want.

Comment: I mark this as answered but i knew about this. I rather was searching for interface like in WinMerge. Or something like "Copy selected line to left window"

Comment: I think that is not allowed in kdiff3, because the compare vision is read-only. You can only change things in a merge view.

Answer (score 0):

Use DiffMerge instead. Its free and much better than kdiff

http://www.sourcegear.com/diffmerge/